# Javascript Method Chaining: Correct method chain toFixed() and parseFloat() to return a number, not a string?

Tags: javascript, parsefloat, tofixed

Most important thing here is that I can NOT set a variable, needs to be on the fly:

Dealing with latitude. Let's call it lat. Let's say in this case lat is 123.4567

```
lat.toFixed(2).parseFloat();

TypeError: Object 123.35 has no method 'parseFloat'
```

Best way to go about this?

Comment: Well, you need to pass something to `parseFloat`, which is a function and not a method, so...`parseFloat(lat.toFixed(2));`. If you wanted to be able to use chaining, you could modify `String`'s prototype, like: `String.prototype.parseFloat = function () { return parseFloat(this); };` - http://jsfiddle.net/L4M2C/

Comment: Yep you're right, I just completely overlooked it. `parseFloat(Lat).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a method of [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and returns a string. [`window.parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) is a global function and not a method of [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), but if you really must, then you can make it a `String` method, otherwise just use it as a function. You can even use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators?redirect=no) operator in this case.

*(There is a great deal of discussion about augmenting native objects that I am not going to go into, you can do some research and make up your own mind.)*

Javascript

```
if (!String.prototype.parseFloat) {
    String.prototype.parseFloat = function () {
        return parseFloat(this);
    }
}

var lat = 123.456789;

console.log(parseFloat(lat.toFixed(2)));
console.log(lat.toFixed(2).parseFloat());
console.log(+lat.toFixed(2));
```

Output

```
123.46
123.46 
123.46
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/P549R/)

Comment: There's not really that much controversy for changing the `String` prototype. Now, `Array` and `Object` are another thing...

Comment: I agree, but it depends on the circles you travel in.

Comment: True, I've just never heard anything against it specifically. Something important though is checking that the method doesn't already exist. Like `"".parseFloat || String.prototype.parseFloat = function () { /* Stuff */ };`

Comment: Sure, in this simple case I didn't think it necessary but I will add it for completeness.

Comment: And I hope the edits I just made were okay; feel free to revert or anything :)

Comment: Well, even in simple cases, you never know if it's there, so it can't hurt to encourage checking. No big deal :)

Comment: @Xotic750 what if I am trying to add two decimal the trailing zeros are missing! 

+(parseFloat(3.6 + 4.4).toFixed(1))

if I use .toFixed it returns string and parseFloat return number but without decimal point/trailing zero

Comment: To have trailing zeros for display it has to be a string, that's just the way JS is.